# Is pysftp really context-aware?

Tags: python, ftp, contextmanager, pysftp

I'm using the pysftp module to implement a function to put some files onto an FTP site.  Following the suggestion in the cookbook for version 0.29, I opened the connection in a with statement:

```
with psyftp.Connection(host=SERVER, port=PORT, username=USER, password=PASS) as ftp:
```

(I know using all caps for parameter names is not ideal python style.  Please don't judge.) Running this results in:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Research on StackOverflow says this happens because the `with` statement requires an object that has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.  You get this error when you use `with` on an object that doesn't include them, i.e., not a context manager.

Is pysftp not really a context manager, despite its claim, or is there something more subtle going on?  I can program my routine without relying on the "with" statement, I'm just wondering what the deal is here.

Answer (score 0):

Contextmanager is working on the current version:

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection(self.server_ip, username=self.username, password=self.password) as sftp:
    for attr in sftp.listdir_attr(remotepath=remote_path):
        print(attr.filename, attr.st_size, sftp.isdir(remote_path + "/" + attr.filename))
```

> Note: PYSFPT != FTP, if you like to connect to a FTP server please use
>   `ftplib`

```
from ftplib import FTP
with FTP("ftp1.at.proftpd.org") as ftp:
    #do your stuff here
```

*SFTP = SSH File Transfer Protocol, FTP = File Transfer Protocol*

> FTPS (also known as FTPES, FTP-SSL, and FTP Secure) is an extension to
>   the commonly used File Transfer Protocol (FTP) that adds support for
>   the Transport Layer Security (TLS) and, formerly, the Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL, which is now prohibited by RFC7568) cryptographic
>   protocols.
>
> FTPS should not be confused with the SSH File Transfer Protocol
>   (SFTP), a secure file transfer subsystem for the Secure Shell (SSH)
>   protocol with which it is not compatible. It is also different from
>   FTP over SSH, which is the practice of tunneling FTP through an SSH
>   connection. - [FTPS Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS)